# Traducir una consulta SQL a LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Soy muy nueva usando LINQ y he hecho pocas cosas, ahorita tengo una consulta SQL que debo implementar en LINQ y no tengo ni idea de cómo se hace.

```
SELECT Boletas.Boleta, DATEPART(DW, CAST(Boletas.Fecha AS datetime)) AS DiaDeLaSemana, 
       Materiales.Descripcion, Clientes.Nombre, 
       induscomer.NoCliente AS induscomerNoCliente
FROM   Boletas 
       INNER JOIN Materiales 
       ON Boletas.Material = Materiales.Material AND Boletas.Familia = Materiales.Familia 
       INNER JOIN Clientes 
       ON Boletas.NoCliente = Clientes.NoCliente 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN induscomer 
       ON Clientes.NoCliente = induscomer.NoCliente
WHERE  (Boletas.Fecha >= '20170101') AND (Boletas.Fecha <= '20170107') 
       AND (Boletas.Status = 'A')
ORDER BY Boletas.Material
```

De tal forma que si no existe el correspondiente cliente en la tabla **induscomer**, entonces *induscomerNoCliente* sería nulo.

Intenté siguiendo algunas ayudas que encontré hacerlo así:

```
var boletaQuery = (
    from b in _context.Boletas
    join m in _context.Materiales on b.Material equals m.Material
    join c in _context.Clientes on b.NoCliente equals c.NoCliente
    join i in _context.induscomer on c.NoCliente equals i.NoCliente into indus
    from ind in indus.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where b.Fecha.CompareTo(FechaIni) >= 0
        && b.Fecha.CompareTo(FechaFin) <= 0
        && b.Status.Equals('A')
    select new { 
        b, 
        induscomerNoCliente = ind.NoCliente, 
        NombreCliente = c.Nombre, 
        DescripcionMaterial = m.Descripcion 
    }
);
```

Pero al hacer `boletaQuery.ToList();` me marca el siguiente error:

> Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.NotSupportedException' en System.Data.Entity.dll
>   Información adicional: No se pudo crear un valor de constante de tipo 'System.Object'. Solo se admiten tipos primitivos o tipos de enumeración en este contexto.

Comment: A simple vista tu consulta en `LINQ` esta bien estructurada, pero de pronto si tienes problemas con el `where`. No utilices `CompareTo` o `Equals` te recomiendo que utilices `b.Fecha >= fecha && b.Fecha <= fecha && b.Status == 'A'`

Comment: muchas gracias  Weimar Yamit, voy a revisarlo

Comment: @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez hice un abreviado para probar, y pues el problema es en left join, pues me marca el mismo error dejando solamente en el query: var boletaQuery = (from b in _context.Boletas
                    join i in _context.induscomer on b.NoCliente equals i.NoCliente into indus
                    from ind in indus.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new { b, induscomerNoCliente = ind.NoCliente}
                        );

Comment: Cyndy, Intenta por favor lo siguiente: `var boletaQuery = (from b in _context.Boletas join i in _context.induscomer on b.NoCliente equals i.NoCliente into indus from ind in indus.DefaultIfEmpty() select new { b, induscomerNoCliente = (ind == null ? String.Empty : ind.NoCliente)} );` y me cuentas si te sigue mostrando el error.

Comment: ok, lo checo @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez, gracias

Comment: @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez, ya lo chequé y me marcaba que no hay una conversion implicita de string a int, traté de ponerle Convert.ToInt32(String.Empty), pero al ejecutar el linq marca que "LINQ to Entities no reconoce el método 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' del método, y este método no se puede traducir en una expresión de almacén."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pues muchísimas gracias a todos por sus aportes, siguiendo los consejos de @YanetSilvaFernández,  @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez, @Flxtr y luego de un montón de pruebas el LEFT OUTER JOIN ya quedó:

```
 var boletaQuery =
        from b in _context.Boletas
        join m in _context.Materiales 
        on new { k1 = (int?)b.Familia, k2 = (int?)b.Material } 
        equals new { k1 = (int?)m.Familia, k2 = (int?)m.Material }
        join c in _context.Clientes on b.NoCliente equals c.NoCliente
        join i in _context.induscomer on c.NoCliente equals i.NoCliente into indus
        from ind in indus.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where b.Fecha.CompareTo(FechaIni) >= 0 && b.Fecha.CompareTo(FechaFin) <= 0 
        && b.Status.Equals("A")
        select new
        {
            b,
            DiaDeLaSemana = SqlFunctions.DatePart("DW", b.Fecha),
            DescripcionMaterial = m.Descripcion,
            NombreCliente = c.Nombre,
            ind
        };
```

Luego cargo los datos a mi estructura en la que definí el campo induscomerNoCliente como int? (que permite nulos) con el siguiente ciclo:

```
        int? indusnocliente;
        foreach (var item in boletaQuery.ToList())
        {
            if (item.ind == null)
            {
                indusnocliente = null;
            }
            else
            {
                indusnocliente = item.ind.NoCliente;
            }
            lsOperacion.Add(new OperacionCL
            {
                Base = item.b.Base,
                Boleta = item.b.Boleta,
                Fecha = item.b.Fecha,
                Contado = (float)item.b.Contado.Value,
                Credito = (float)item.b.Credito.Value,
                Material = (int)item.b.Material.Value,
                Neto = (float)item.b.Neto.Value,
                Total = (float)item.b.Total.Value,
                NombreCliente = item.NombreCliente,
                DescripcionMaterial = item.DescripcionMaterial,
                DoW = (int)item.DiaDeLaSemana, 
                induscomerNoCliente = indusnocliente
            });
        }
```

Saludos y gracias de nuevo

Comment: Es bueno que hayas encontrado tu solución pero es aún mejor que la hayas compartido con la comunidad :D

Answer (score 4):

Existe una herramienta que te puede ayudar, se llama <kbd>[Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/)</kbd>. Esta herramienta te puede ayudar a convertir un *query* de SQL a Linq y viceversa.

Te recomiendo que lo utilices, veas el comportamiento que tiene al realizar las conversiones y sobre todo asimiles que es bastante parecido, aunque de primera instancia pareciera que SQL y Linq son totalmente diferentes, no lo veas por ese lado.

De igual forma te recomiendo que revises la [documentación oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) (en inglés) y veas cómo empezar a trabajar con Linq.

Comment: muchas gracias Flxtr, voy a revisarlo

Answer (score 2):

Esto me funcionó:

```
var context = new DBContext();
            var boletaQuery =
                from b in context.Boletas
                from m in context.Materiales
                from c in context.Clientes
                join i in context.Induscomer on c.NoCliente equals i.NoCliente into indus
                from ind in indus.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where
                b.Material == m.Material && b.Familia == m.Familia && b.NoCliente == c.NoCliente && b.Fecha >= fechaIni &&
                b.Fecha <= fechaFin && b.Status.Equals('A')
                select new
                {
                    b.Boleta,
                    DiaDeLaSemana = SqlFunctions.DatePart("DW", b.Fecha),
                    m.Descripcion,
                    NombreCliente = c.Nombre,
                    induscomerNoCliente = ind.NoCliente
                };
            var result = boletaQuery.ToList();
```

...........................

```
var boletaQuery =
            from b in context.Boletas
            join m in context.Materiales on new { b.Familia, b.Material } equals new { m.Familia, m.Material }
            join c in context.Clientes on b.NoCliente equals c.NoCliente
            join i in context.Induscomer on c.NoCliente equals i.NoCliente into indus
            from ind in indus.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where b.Fecha >= fechaIni && b.Fecha <= fechaFin && b.Status == 'A'
            select new
            {
                b.Boleta,
                DiaDeLaSemana = SqlFunctions.DatePart("DW", b.Fecha),
                m.Descripcion,
                NombreCliente = c.Nombre,
                induscomerNoCliente = ind.NoCliente
            };
```

.........................
Este es el plan de ejecución de ambas consultas en sql y tienen el mismo costo. ([¿Cual es la diferencia entre joins implícitos y explícitos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52530/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-joins-impl%C3%ADcitos-y-expl%C3%ADcitos))

[image: JOIN]

[image: WHERE]

Comment: Hola Yanet, utilizar `join` implicitos con Linq no estoy seguro que realmente funcione, y suponiendo que funcione es una funcionalidad deprecada y por tal motivo se recomienda utilizar los `join` explicitos :)

Comment: El código funciona, pues lo probé antes de subir la respuesta. Con respecto a los joins implicitos o explicitos tienes toda la razón, acá les pongo como ponerlo todo como explicito:

Comment: muchas gracias @YanetSilvaFernández, lo voy a probar, luego te cuento

Comment: Cindy, sería bueno saber los tipos de datos con los que estas trabajando en cada unas de las columnas implicadas en la consulta.

Comment: si @YanetSilvaFernández, de hecho por allí tengo detalles, por ejemplo la **Fecha** es varchar(8) trae datos como _'20170101'_, *Familia (int,null)*, *Material (int,null)*,  *NoCliente (int,null)*, *Boleta (int, not null)*, *Clientes.Nombre varchar(75)*, *Materiales.Descripcion varchar(50)*

Comment: Básicamente son los mismo tipos de datos que utilice para el ejemplo. Si no te funciona me avisas y te mando el proyecto por correo y revisas.

Comment: muchas gracias @YanetSilvaFernández, ejecuté la primera opción que me envias (join implicito) y me sale exactamente el mismo error que me salía (el que publiqué en el post) y con la segunda opción (join explicito) no me permite el join que lleva el on new { b.Familia, b.Material } equals new { m.Familia, m.Material }, pues me pone subraya en rojo el join y dice: "El tipo de una de las expresiones de la cláusula join es incorrecto. No se pudo realizar inferencia de tipos en la llamada a join"

Comment: @YanetSilvaFernández , revisando las tablas del join en Basculas, Familia y Material son de tipo (int, null) y en Materiales son (int, not null) pues forman parte del pk, será por eso?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56324/discussion-between-yanet-silva-fernandez-and-cyndy).

Answer (score 2):

Interesante tu pregunta, pero fuera de averiguar como convertirla, sugiero que pruebes este software:

[LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)

Es una herramienta muy útil, te puede servir para probar el código de linq directo sobre la conexión de la BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este otro programa hace lo que necesitas convertir SQL to linq:

[sqltolinq](http://www.sqltolinq.com/)

Al parecer son de paga ambos :(

Comment: muchas gracias, la voy a checar