# ¿Cómo puedo reemplazar un ID por Nombre al hacer un llamado de MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Este es mi dilema, tengo 2 tablas estructuradas así:

```
 ************    ********************
 * Producto *    * Tipo de Producto *
 ************    ********************
 * ID       *    * ID               *
 * Nombre   *    * Nombre           *
 * Tipo     *    ********************
 ************
```

En `Productos.Tipo` el valor es un `ID` en la tabla `Tipo de producto`, una relación uno a muchos.

Solo quiero saber cómo hacer que al llamar datos de productos, al llamar tipo, en vez de retornarme un ID de Tipo de productos, me retorne el valor `Nombre` que hay en Tipo de producto según el ID en Producto.

Le pregunté a una profesora pero lo que me dio fue este *query*:

```
SELECT Producto.ID
    ,Producto.Nombre
    ,Tipo_de_Producto.Nombre
FROM Producto
    ,Tipo_de_Producto
WHERE Producto.Tipo = Tipo_de_Producto.ID
    AND Producto.ID = 'loquesea'
```

Answer (score 2):

Sería cuestión de hacer un `LEFT JOIN` u otro tipo de `JOIN` usando la columna `tipo_id`, que es clave primaria de la tabla `productos_tipo` y es clave foránea en la tabla `productos`.

Con el `LEFT JOIN`, si hay un producto que no tiene valor en la columna `tipo_id`, se mostrará de todos modos el nombre del producto y en la columna de la derecha habrá un valor `NULL`.

Eso ya dependerá de lo que quieras hacer. Los JOIN estás explicados aquí: [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un inner y un outer join?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-un-inner-y-un-outer-join)

Se puede también hacer, si se necesita, filtros del tipo `WHERE` por ejemplo, o agrupaciones, usando cualquiera de las columnas de las dos tablas.

Para más claridad me gusta usar *alias* de tabla de este modo:

`productos p... productos_tipos pt` y luego cuando hay que referirse a cualquier columna de ellas sólo se usa `p.columna` o `pt.columna`.

Este es un ejemplo completo. Fíjate en **Query 1** y **Query 2** más abajo.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/849b72/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE productos
    (`producto_id` int, `producto_nom` varchar(30), `tipo_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO productos
    (`producto_id`, `producto_nom`, `tipo_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Arroz', 1),
    (2, 'Pantalón', 2),
    (3, 'Jabón', 3),
    (4, 'Pescado', 1);

CREATE TABLE productos_tipos
    (`tipo_id` int, `tipo_nom` varchar(30))
;

INSERT INTO productos_tipos
    (`tipo_id`, `tipo_nom`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Alimentos'),
    (2, 'Ropa'),
    (3, 'Limpieza');
```

**Query 1**:

```
-- Quiero todo


SELECT
  p.producto_nom, pt.tipo_nom
FROM
  productos p
LEFT JOIN productos_tipos pt
  ON p.tipo_id=pt.tipo_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/849b72/2/0)**:

```
| producto_nom |  tipo_nom |
|--------------|-----------|
|        Arroz | Alimentos |
|      Pescado | Alimentos |
|     Pantalón |      Ropa |
|        Jabón |  Limpieza |
```

**Query 2**:

```
 -- Quiero sólo arroz 

SELECT
  p.producto_nom, pt.tipo_nom
FROM
  productos p
LEFT JOIN productos_tipos pt
  ON p.tipo_id=pt.tipo_id
  WHERE p.producto_id=1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/849b72/2/1)**:

```
| producto_nom |  tipo_nom |
|--------------|-----------|
|        Arroz | Alimentos |
```

Comment: muchas gracias, no conocia esa funcion joint

Answer (score 0):

Es importante evitar el uso de un `join` implícito, ya que es una funcionalidad deprecada, lo ideal es hacer el uso de un `join` explícito. Si deseas más información acerca de las diferencias y su uso revisa esta excelente respuesta que detalla todo para su entendiemiento:

- [**¿Cual es la diferencia entre joins implícitos y explícitos?**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53988/16841)

Ahora, para transormar tu consulta a un `join` explícito sería con:

```
SELECT Producto.ID
    ,P.Nombre
    ,TP.Nombre
FROM Producto P
    INNER JOIN Tipo_de_Producto TP 
        ON P.Tipo = TP.ID
WHERE P.ID = 'loquesea'
```

Esta consulta crea la relación que existe entre ambas tablas, entonces, al enviar como condición el `ID` del producto a su vez estás seleccionando de igual forma los datos del tipo de producto con `TP.Nombre`.

Comment: gracias, muchas gracias