# Actualizar la columna de una tabla restando el valor de columna de otra tabla en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola buenas noches! Estoy creando las consultas de mi primera db;
quiero actualizar el atributo `WEIGHT_PURCH` de la entidad `packing_lists`
restando el valor del atributo `WEIGHT_SOLD` de la entidad `orders`,
relacionadas de 1 a N, estando la FK en la entidad `orders` que es
el atributo `packinglists_id` relacionada con el id de la entidad `packing_lists`.

Este es el código como estaba haciendo la consulta, ¡me arroja error de sintaxis!

```
UPDATE packing_lists 
SET weight_purcha = weight_purcha - weight_sold 
FROM packing_lists pl, orders o 
WHERE pl.id = o.packinglist_id;
```

Como les comenté es mi primera base de datos y lo estoy haciendo para tener el stock de los productos que se registran por número de lote y al registrar órdenes de ventas se actualice el peso de lo que ingreso.

Si hay otra manera que se pueda hacer o hay forma de hacerlo teniendo ustedes más experiencia, ¡estaré agradecido! ¡Gracias!

Comment: ¿Nos pasas el dataset (phpMyAdmin, Exportar) para probar la consulta y ver qué error da?

Comment: sera que el campo se llama weight_purch y no weight_purcha????

Comment: Y siempre que tengas un error, decinos cual es... no sabemos cual es el error que te da...

Comment: Este es error que me da gbianchi! No ya el nombre del campo lo corregi e igual me da el error aun colocando las 2 opciones que aporto Emiliano! Este es el error: 0 103 03:41:15 UPDATE packing_lists 
 SET packing_lists.weight_purchased = (packing_lists.weight_purchased - orders.weight_sold) 
 INNER JOIN orders ON packing_lists.id = orders.packinglist_id Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN orders ON packing_lists.id = orders.packinglist_id' at line 3 0.000 sec

Answer (score -1):

Por lo que veo, tú código no se ve tan mal. Lo que observo es que pusiste alias a las tablas y luego solo utilizaste los nombres de los fields sin el alias. Otra cosa que veo es que haces un binding de las tablas a la antigua, prueba utilizando joins (aquí una explicación de la diferencia entre join y where [¿Cual es la diferencia de hacer un INNER JOIN con ON y con Where?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157146/cual-es-la-diferencia-de-hacer-un-inner-join-con-on-y-con-where)), te dejo 2 opciones que puedes implementar dado que no especificas si utilizas mysql o sqlserver (u otra):

OPCION 1:

```
UPDATE PLS SET PLS.weight_purch = (PLS.weight_purch - O.weight_sold) 
FROM packing_lists PLS
INNER JOIN orders O ON PLS.id = O.packinglist_id;
```

OPCION 2:

```
UPDATE packing_lists PLS SET PLS.weight_purcha = (PLS.weight_purcha - O.weight_sold) 
INNER JOIN orders O ON PLS.id = O.packinglist_id;
```

Cuentanos como te fue!. Slds.

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).