# Ayuda Consulta JOINS ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle-sqldeveloper

Crear un select donde se muestre el nombre y apellido del empleado, departamento donde labora y el nombre y apellido del manager que lo coordina.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME||' '||EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME AS "NOMBRE COMPLETO DEL EMPLEADO",DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID,DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME,DEPARTMENTS.MANAGER_ID FROM EMPLOYEES,DEPARTMENTS WHERE EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID=DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Buenas necesito ayuda para esta consulta el problemas es que no se como sacar el nombre y apellido del manager que coordina el departamento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que requieres en este caso es hacer un `SELF JOIN`, es decir, hacer la unión de tablas con la misma tabla de `EMPLOYEES` para poder encontrar la información del manager.

El primer punto a corregir es dejar de usar `JOIN` implícito y empezar a usar `JOIN` explícito, ya que la funcionalidad de usar `JOIN` implícito se considera deprecada desde 1992.

La consulta quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT 
     E.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || E.LAST_NAME AS "NOMBRE COMPLETO DEL EMPLEADO"
    ,D.DEPARTMENT_ID
    ,D.DEPARTMENT_NAME
    ,D.MANAGER_ID
    ,EE.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || EE.LAST_NAME AS "NOMBRE COMPLETO DEL MANAGER"
FROM EMPLOYEES E
    INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS D
        ON E.DEPARMENT_ID = D.DEPARMENT_ID
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES EE
        ON E.MANAGER_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

La magia ocurre en el `JOIN`:

```
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES EE
        ON E.MANAGER_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

Si logras notar, al igualar el campo `MANAGER_ID` con `EMPLOYEE_ID` estás diciendo que vas o obtener los datos del manager a través de su id de empleado, ya que el manager es de igual manera un empleado más.

Nota: Para mayor información acerca de las diferencias entre `JOIN` implícito y `JOIN` explícito, esta [gran respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52530/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-joins-impl%C3%ADcitos-y-expl%C3%ADcitos/53988#53988) te puede aclarar el panorama.

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo la respuesta anterior como base a mi me funcionó asi

```
SELECT E.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || E.LAST_NAME AS EMPLEADO, 
       D.DEPARTMENT_NAME AS DEPARTAMENTO, 
       EE.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || EE.LAST_NAME AS MANAGER 
       FROM EMPLOYEES E, 
            DEPARTMENTS D 
       JOIN EMPLOYEES EE 
            ON (D.MANAGER_ID=EE.EMPLOYEE_ID);
```