# Ayuda con una Query en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 2 tablas, 1 de alumnos y otra llamada alumno_matricula

necesito hacer un select de la tabla alumnos, obtener su id y con esa id entrar a la tabla de alumno_matricula y mostrar el numero de matricula

la tabla alumnos es asi:

```
id string,
nombres string,
direccion string,
edad int
```

y la tabla alumno_matricula es asi

```
alumno_id,
numero_matricula,
fecha_matricula
```

necesito mostrar el nombre del alumno y su numero de matricula

por ejemplo

David 2832-1234

Intente hacerla con un select from join pero no me resulta de este modo

```
SELECT e.nombres, e.id 
FROM alumnos e JOIN alumno_matricula e2 SELECT e2.numero_matricula WHERE e.id = e2.alumno_id
```

Comment: Que base de datos es?SQL SERVER,MYSQL en los tags tienes de todo

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder es MYSQL

Comment: Pon la consulta que has intentado

Comment: SELECT e.nombres, e.id FROM alumnos e
JOIN alumno_matricula e2 SELECT e2.numero_matricula WHERE e.id = e2.alumno_id

Comment: SELECT e.nombres, e.id, e2.numero_matricula
FROM alumnos e 
INNER JOIN alumno_matricula e2 ON e.id = e2.alumno_id

Comment: Edgar muchas gracias, me esta funcionando, pero como puedo hacer que me muestre NULL si no tiene numero de matricula  ?

Comment: En vez de un INNER Pon un LEFT JOIN.
SELECT e.nombres, e.id, e2.numero_matricula FROM alumnos e LEFT JOIN alumno_matricula e2 ON e.id = e2.alumno_id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hola puedes usar esto

```
SELECT e.nombres, e.id, e2.numero_matricula
    FROM alumnos e INNER JOIN alumno_matricula e2 ON e.id = e2.alumno_id
```

Con esto igualas los id y puedes acceder a el valor de la matricula, en caso de que el alumno no tenga matricula podrias usar algo como esto para mostar el valor en NULL

```
SELECT e.nombres, e.id, e2.numero_matricula 
FROM alumnos e LEFT JOIN alumno_matricula e2 ON e.id = e2.alumno_id
```

Y si quisieras mostrar algo en especifico en vez de null podria ser

```
SELECT e.nombres, e.id, COALESCE(e2.numero_matricula ,'Sin matricula')
FROM alumnos e LEFT JOIN alumno_matricula e2 ON e.id = e2.alumno_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa un `INNER JOIN` de este modo:

```
SELECT alumnos.nombres, alumno_matricula.numero_matricula
FROM alumnos
JOIN alumno_matricula ON alumnos.id = alumno_matriculas.alumno_id;
```

**Explicación**

- Donde para obtener los datos de las tablas, lo haces a través de las columnas que las relacionan que son: llave primaria (alumnos.id) y llave foránea(matricula_alumnos.alumno_id)
- No necesitas hacer 2 veces un `SELECT` para obtener los datos, dentro del mismo lo logras solo escribiendo `tablaNombre1.columna`, `tablaNombre2.columna`
- `INNER JOIN` o solo `JOIN` lo que hace es obtener los datos de ambas tablas, donde el registro de la izquierda (id) coincida con el registro de la derecha (alumno_id) y descartando a los demás

Noto en tus comentarios que deseas también aquellos que no tienen matrícula; entonces deberás usar `LEFT JOIN` para que el resultado considere tanto aquellos registros que coinciden en ambas tablas como aquellos registros del lado izquierdo(alumnos) que no tienen vínculo con la tabla de la derecha (matricula_alumnos)

**Fuentes de consulta**

- [`JOIN` Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que indicar que tipo de JOIN es, existen 3 tipos, `LEFT JOIN`, `INNER JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` para entender cada tipo te recomiendo buscar información acerca de cada uno que hay en internet, [Un ejemplo](https://www.vichaunter.org/desarrollo-web/joins-mysql-bien-explicado-lo-necesitas-saber). En este caso se requiere `INNER JOIN`, se debe indicar la condición del JOIN con `ON`, y el select de ambas tablas va en un solo `SELECT`, no en dos, por lo que tu consulta quedaría

```
SELECT e.nombres, e.id e2.numero_matricula
FROM alumnos e 
INNER JOIN alumno_matricula e2 ON e.id = e2.alumno_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente a mi se me complican un poco los JOIN, por eso suelo usar instrucciones planas... Algo así debería funcionar 100%

```
   SELECT nombres, id, numero_matricula FROM alumnos, alumno_matricula WHERE alumnos.id= alumno_matricula.alumno_id
```

Comment: Lo que haces es un `JOIN` implícito y aunque es funcional, me parece no forma parte del estandard SQL

Comment: Tienes bastante razón ....  aquí una explicación amplia del tema ...   https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52530/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-joins-impl%c3%adcitos-y-expl%c3%adcitos