# Mostrar datos de 2 tablas relacionadas

Tags: mysql, sql

Soy algo nuevo en esto y estoy intentando que aparezcan todas las subcategorías, pero solamente aparece una

Ya probé con foreach, pero no funciono, aunque no descarto que haya echo algo mal

Este es el código:

```
<?php
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT categorias.*, subcategorias.* FROM categorias, subcategorias WHERE categorias.id = subcategorias.id ORDER BY subcategorias.id ASC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    ?>
    <li>
        <a class="parent" href="#"><?php echo $row['ctitulo'];?></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row['stitulo'];?></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Categorias
[image: Categorias]

Subcategorias
[image: Subcategorias]

Answer (score 1):

**Parte 1**

Considero que el problema lo tienes aquí:

```
WHERE categorias.id = subcategorias.id
```

Puesto que en la condición estás solicitando filas únicamente cuando las llaves primarias en ambas tablas empaten, sin embargo:

- Si existen menos categorías que subcategorías entonces las subcategorías sobrantes es decir que su PK no tengan su correspondiente valor no serán parte de la salida

**Parte 2**

Considera revisar lo siguiente:

- Recomiendo te des una vuelta por la doc. [de la herramienta que usas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) para que leas al respecto de *llaves foráneas*, puesto que su uso no es visible en la muestra de tus tablas
- Recomiendo leas [acá sobre *`JOINS`*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)
- Además la sintaxis de joins que usas no es la adecuada, recomiendo [leas este aporte que ya existe en la comunidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52530/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-joins-impl%c3%adcitos-y-expl%c3%adcitos) donde se habla mas al respecto

Si hablamos de que *una categoría tiene muchas subcategorías* entonces la consulta puede quedar de esta forma:

```
SELECT categorias.*, subcategorias.*
FROM categorias
INNER JOIN subcategorias ON categorias.id = subcategorias.categoria_id;
```

Usamos la sintaxis regular de joins y en la condición indicamos que las filas devueltas serán siempre y cuando la llave primaria de las categorías sea igual a la llave foránea almacenada por cada fila de las subcategorías.

Es decir algo (*muy reducido*) de esta forma:

```
categorias        subcategorias
id                id
......            ..........
......            ..........
                  categoria_id <----- esta sería la llave foránea
```

Donde tendré la salida esperada que es:

- Todas las categorías que tengan al menos una subcategoría asociada por medio de su correspondencia entre llave primaria y llave foránea.

**Edición**

- Debemos [agrupar de forma concatenada](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) sus N filas relacionadas
- Debemos [agrupar](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) para reducir las filas que aparecen repetidas

Quedando así la consulta:

```
SELECT categorias.nombre, GROUP_CONCAT(subcategorias.nombre)
FROM categorias
INNER JOIN subcategorias ON categorias.id = subcategorias.categoria_id
GROUP BY categorias.nombre;
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, es mi primera vez preguntando y me sorprendió ver tanta ayuda. Ya voy a chequear lo de las llaves foráneas, de los joins ya leí un poco, pero leeré eso que me pasaste también 

Comment: Una pregunta más, se soluciono lo anterior, ahora aparecen todas las subcategorías, pero las categorías se duplican, ósea, si hay una categoría con dos subcategorías o más, está se duplica, no se si me explico, ahí te paso una foto. Esto es lo que sucede: https://i.ibb.co/bsYYsgb/2.png

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me has salvado!! 