# Agregar a consulta de mysql datos que no están relacionados

Tags: mysql, sql, subconsultas

Tengo esta consulta en MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM admin_vln.user, admin_vln.device 
WHERE admin_vln.user.id_user = admin_vln.device.id_user_device
```

Que lo que hace es devolver una nueva tabla mostrando todos los datos de la tabla **user** y **devices** en donde se cumple que el campo **id_user** de la tabla **user** es igual al campo **id_user_device** de la tabal **device**.

El problema es que algunos datos de la tabla **devices** en la columna **id_user_device** estan **NULL** y no me los agrega a la consulta. Como hago para que tambien los agregue a la consulta pormar de que no este asociado a ningun user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según lo que se expone en tu pregunta: *un user puede tener muchos devices* y es en la tabla devices donde se almacena como llave foránea el id del usuario con el dispositivo relacionado.

Tomando en cuenta lo anterior, entonces la consulta podría componerse de esta forma:

```
SELECT * FROM admin_vln.user
RIGHT JOIN admin_vln.device ON admin_vln.user.id_user = admin_vln.device.id_user_device
```

Así obtendrías todos los usuarios (*de la izquierda*) mas los dispositivos (*de la derecha*) que no están relacionados con alguno de ellos.

Puedo recomendar leas:

- [*`joins`*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)
- [Publicación en la comunidad respecto de la sintaxis de joins](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53988/128299)

Answer (score 1):

Existen varios formas de juntar dos tablas, una es aplicando la forma que ya usas en tu ejemplo, es decir:

```
select columnas
from tabla1, tabla2
where tabla1.id = tabla2.id;
```

Otra forma es aplicando la **claúsula** **inner join**, que solamente va a juntar las dos tablas si el campo que se usa para hacer la relación es común en ambas tablas:

```
select columnas
from tabla1 inner join tabla2 on tabla1.id = tabla2.id;
```

Esta forma hace lo mismo que la de tu ejemplo pero es más legible, ya que entre otras cosas la consulta suele ser más corta y la **claúsula** **where** no se usa para establecer la relación entre las tablas.

Para darle solución a tu problema puedes usar las **claúsulas** **left join** o **right join:**

```
select columnas
from tabla1 left join tabla2 on tabla1.id = tabla2.id;
```

En esta consulta se usa la **claúsula** **left join**, la cual permite juntar las dos tablas coincidan o no las columnas por las que se hace la comparación, es decir en caso de que hayan coincidencias entre las columnas que se comparan, se establece la relación como hasta ahora, pero en caso de que no hayan coincidencias se muestra a la izquierda los datos de **tabla1** y a la derecha como no hay coincidencia se rellena esa fila con valores **null**:

```
select columnas
from tabla1 right join tabla2 on tabla1.id = tabla2.id;
```

Aquí ocurre lo mismo salvo que en caso de que no hayan coincidencias se muestra a la derecha los datos de **tabla2** y a la izquierda como no hay coincidencia se rellena esa fila con valores **null**.