# Diferencia entre Where y join on en SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql, join, where

estoy empezando con SQL en la uni y me ha surgido la siguiente duda, ¿tienen alguna diferencia estos dos códigos?

```
SELECT e.id, e.nombre FROM Estudiante e, Clase c WHERE e.cid=c.cid and c.cid=1;
```

y

```
SELECT e.id, e.nombre FROM Estudiante e join Clase c on e.cid=c.cid where c.cid=1;
```

Si no hay diferencias, ¿para que existe join?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cual es la diferencia entre joins implícitos y explícitos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52530/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-joins-impl%c3%adcitos-y-expl%c3%adcitos). El primero es un `JOIN` implícito, y el segundo es un `JOIN`explícito. Hacen lo mismo, no ha diferencia en el rendimiento. Para mi gusto, los `JOIN` implícitos son más claros, sobre todo cuando participan varias tablas, puedes ver con más claridad quién se relaciona con quién y es la forma estándar.

Comment: @A.Cedano creo que quisiste decir que los `JOIN` explícitos son más claros (los que usan la palabra JOIN).

Comment: @LuisCazares sí, me equivoqué en la redacción, **los `JOIN` explícitos** (segundo ejemplo de código de esta pregunta) **son más claros**.